# How can customize the browser drop down select menu, to show styled boxes?

Tags: jquery, css

I have to customize the browser drop down select menu  :

[image]

**to this** :

[image]

How can i achieve that with Jquery or CSS?

I looked in google, and i found some ways to customize the select_menu, but no one to convert it in nice boxes.
Can you give a line where i can found a tutorial for this or help me where to start ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: at this point it is no longer a select menu. Just has the same functionality

Comment: Just use *"radio"* buttons. You don't need selects for this.

Comment: You could use a hidden input field.  Then you update the value of it when the selected size is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI provides some functionality like you describe when using their "radio button" widget.

See the following link for more information: http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Answer (score 2):

You don't want an unordered list for this.

You want radio buttons and labels, and to use the `for=""` attribute.

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmGWN/1/)

You can see that when you click the label, it also selects the respective radio button. Hide the radio buttons using display none (uncomment it from my code) and it performs as you wish.

Comment: +1 for using the next sibling selector instead of JS, but be aware of the [support for the `:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/:checked).